# SonarQube generate PDF report

Tags: java, pdf, jenkins, sonarqube

I have Jenkins to build my Java deployable and then push code into SonarQube for code scanning,
I am able to see the Bug report on SonarQube as well,
But I want a downloadable report in a PDF format or anything that can be shared after the scan.

**I added the following properties in my project's pom.xml-**

```
<properties>
<sonar.analysis.mode>preview</sonar.analysis.mode>       <sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>true</sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>
</properties>
```

**On my local Jenkins I have the following commands -**

```
echo ** Executing SQ Analysis **
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Demo -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java    -Dsonar.login=[someKey] -Dsonar.ProjectName=Demo -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

**I am getting the following error while trying to build -**

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Linear-ingestion ---
[INFO] Installing /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/user/.m2/repository/com/cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/pom.xml to /home/user/.m2/repository/com/cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to /home/user/.m2/repository/com/cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 26.531 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-04T13:41:08+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/pom.xml to com.cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to com.cloudlytics/Linear-ingestion/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Linear-ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[Linear] $ /bin/sh -xe /home/user/office/R&D/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/temp/jenkins3011322823073246601.sh
channel stopped
+ echo RemoteSystemsTempFiles bin log4j.properties pom.xml src target Executing SQ Analysis RemoteSystemsTempFiles bin log4j.properties pom.xml src target
RemoteSystemsTempFiles bin log4j.properties pom.xml src target Executing SQ Analysis RemoteSystemsTempFiles bin log4j.properties pom.xml src target
+ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Linear -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.login=f51956611fa53b292bb19e25752cb22b5afe893e -Dsonar.ProjectName=Linear sonar-runner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.cloudlytics:Linear-ingestion:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-core:jar -> version ${springframework.version} vs ${spring.version} @ line 52, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> version ${springframework.version} vs ${org.springframework-version} @ line 67, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.cloudlytics:Linear-ingestion >------------------
[INFO] Building Linear-ingestion 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) @ Linear-ingestion ---
[INFO] User cache: /home/user/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.7.4
[INFO] Default locale: "en_IN", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Issues mode
[WARNING] The use of the issues mode (sonar.analysis.mode=issues) is deprecated. This mode will be dropped in the future.
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=454ms
[INFO] Server id: AWRKrQutLb-E1SWiQK4O
[INFO] User cache: /home/user/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Exclude plugins: devcockpit, ldap, authgithub, authbitbucket, pdfreport, authaad, googleanalytics, governance
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=141ms
[INFO] Scanning only changed files
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[WARNING] Project doesn't exist on the server. All issues will be marked as 'new'.
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=72ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=2536ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=1558ms
[INFO] Load metrics repository
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=80ms
[INFO] Project key: Linear
[INFO] -------------  Scan Linear-ingestion
[INFO] Load server rules
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=804ms
[INFO] Base dir: /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear
[INFO] Working dir: /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: src/main/java
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_IN
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 68 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 7
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=14ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=2ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 68 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 45/68 files analyzed, current file: /home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/src/main/java/com/blazeclan/sqs_polling_manager/xml/parser/dao/LogicallyDeleteDAO.java
[INFO] 68/68 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=12267ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 0 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 0/0 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=12972ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [/home/user/.jenkins/workspace/Linear/target/surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=11ms
[INFO] Performing issue tracking
[INFO] 79/79 components tracked
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] Task total time: 22.039 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.cloudlytics:Linear-ingestion >------------------
[INFO] Building Linear-ingestion 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 32.370 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-04T13:41:51+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "sonar-runner". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute unexistent `sonar-runner` goal:

> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Demo -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.login=[someKey] -Dsonar.ProjectName=Demo **sonar-runner** -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

You have to remove it:

> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Demo -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.login=[someKey] -Dsonar.ProjectName=Demo -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

I would recommended to remove more parameters:

- `sonar.projectKey` - maven plugin is responsible for generating this parameter
- `sonar.ProjectName` - doesn't exist (correct name is `sonar.projectName`), maven plugin will use vaule of `name` or `artifactId` nodes from your `pom.xml` file
- `sonar.sources=src/main/java` - maven plugin is responsible for generating value of this parameter
- `sonar.analysis.mode=preview` - deprecated and shouldn't be used (since 6.6, you use 6.7.4)
- `sonar.issuesReport.html.enable` - [Issues Report Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin) which uses this parameter is incompatible with SonarQube 6.7.4

Finally you can execute a simple and short command:

> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=[someKey]

Comment: Hi Jenkins is able to build with your shared command -> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Demo -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.login=[someKey] -Dsonar.ProjectName=Demo -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true , But didn't create any report under target directory, what is the location of the SQ report?

Comment: This command does not generate any PDF reports. It only executes an analysis and push results to the server. You have to buy [governance plugin|http://www.sonarplugins.com/governance] which allows you to generate a PDF report. I've never use it, but probably you can generate this report by using Web UI.

Comment: ah ok, I thought there was some opensource way to generate PDF report of the analysis, thanks anyways :)